# sharing images between user control and page

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to pass different images from the user control to page. However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. The method in the UserControl cannot be used in the Page. Does anyone knows any other solution to this?

I'm using ms visual studio 2012, metro app c#

UserControl:

```
    public static BitmapImage ImageFromRelativePath(FrameworkElement parent, string path)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(parent.BaseUri, path);
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        result.UriSource = uri;
        return result;
    }
```

Page:

```
        List<Ghost> ghosts = new List<Ghost>();

        ghosts.Add(new Ghost(1) { MazeValues = mazeValues });
        ghosts.Add(new Ghost(2) { MazeValues = mazeValues });
        ghosts.Add(new Ghost(3) { MazeValues = mazeValues });
        ghosts.Add(new Ghost(4) { MazeValues = mazeValues });
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more please? do you want the usercontrol to create an image and send it back to the page?

Comment: Hi @sLedgem Yes, i want to use the usercontrol to create an image and set the image source in the Page. I need each ghost to have a different image..

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm still a bit unsure about this but here is a shot:

The page ought to have a grid called "LayoutRoot". If it doesn't create one like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

</Grid>
```

then, instead of list (which u can us, but is a bit more complicated), do

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Ghost(1) { MazeValues = mazeValues });
```

Also, it is not a good idea to send parameters in your ghost constructor because it will prevent the ghost usercontrol from displaying when you are in design mode